# Error in filling color in UIImage by using flood fill

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, flood-fill

Thanks to Chintan R Dave's :- [UIImageScanlineFloodfill](https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill)

I am using the following UIImage category to fill colour in closed contour. it uses scanline flood fill algorithm.

It is working fine for images which are not captured from device. for images captured from device it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error (as shown in screen shot given at the end of the question). As you all know this type of error is really hard to get on with.. So i would really appreciate some advise on where to get started for the solution.

the code is as follows :-

**UIImage+FloodFill.m**

```
@implementation UIImage (FloodFill)
/*
    startPoint : Point from where you want to color. Generaly this is touch point.
                 This is important because color at start point will be replaced with other.

    newColor   : This color will be apply at point where the match on startPoint color found.

    tolerance  : If Tolerance is 0 than it will search for exact match of color 
                 other wise it will take range according to tolerance value.

                 If You dont want to use tolerance and want to incress performance Than you can change
                 compareColor(ocolor, color, tolerance) with just ocolor==color which reduse function call.
*/
- (UIImage *) floodFillFromPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint withColor:(UIColor *)newColor andTolerance:(int)tolerance
{
    return [self floodFillFromPoint:startPoint withColor:newColor andTolerance:tolerance useAntiAlias:YES];
}

- (UIImage *) floodFillFromPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint withColor:(UIColor *)newColor andTolerance:(int)tolerance useAntiAlias:(BOOL)antiAlias
{
    @try
    {
        /*
            First We create rowData from UIImage.
            We require this conversation so that we can use detail at pixel like color at pixel.
        */

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage];

        NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
        NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

        unsigned char *imageData = malloc(height * width * 4);

        NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef) / 8;
        NSUInteger bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);
        NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);

        CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
        if (kCGImageAlphaLast == (uint32_t)bitmapInfo || kCGImageAlphaFirst == (uint32_t)bitmapInfo) {
            bitmapInfo = (uint32_t)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
        }

        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData,
                                                     width,
                                                     height,
                                                     bitsPerComponent,
                                                     bytesPerRow,
                                                     colorSpace,
                                                     bitmapInfo);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

        //Get color at start point 
        unsigned int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(startPoint.y)) + roundf(startPoint.x) * bytesPerPixel;

        unsigned int ocolor = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

        if (compareColor(ocolor, 0, 0)) {
            return nil;
        }

        //Convert newColor to RGBA value so we can save it to image.
        int newRed, newGreen, newBlue, newAlpha;

        const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(newColor.CGColor);


        if(CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(newColor.CGColor) == 2)
        {
            newRed   = newGreen = newBlue = components[0] * 255;
            newAlpha = components[1] * 255;
        }
        else if (CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(newColor.CGColor) == 4)
        {
            if ((bitmapInfo&kCGBitmapByteOrderMask) == kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little)
            {
                newRed   = components[2] * 255;
                newGreen = components[1] * 255;
                newBlue  = components[0] * 255;
                newAlpha = 255;
            }
            else
            {
                newRed   = components[0] * 255;
                newGreen = components[1] * 255;
                newBlue  = components[2] * 255;
                newAlpha = 255;
            }
        }

        unsigned int ncolor = (newRed << 24) | (newGreen << 16) | (newBlue << 8) | newAlpha;

        /*
            We are using stack to store point.
            Stack is implemented by LinkList.
            To incress speed I have used NSMutableData insted of NSMutableArray.
        */

        LinkedListStack *points = [[LinkedListStack alloc] initWithCapacity:500 incrementSize:500 andMultiplier:height];
        LinkedListStack *antiAliasingPoints = [[LinkedListStack alloc] initWithCapacity:500 incrementSize:500 andMultiplier:height];

        int x = roundf(startPoint.x);
        int y = roundf(startPoint.y);

        [points pushFrontX:x andY:y];

        /*
            Scanline Floodfill Algorithm With Stack (floodFillScanlineStack)
        */

        unsigned int color;
        BOOL spanLeft,spanRight;

        while ([points popFront:&x andY:&y] != INVALID_NODE_CONTENT)
        {
            byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x) * bytesPerPixel;

            color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

            while(y >= 0 && compareColor(ocolor, color, tolerance))
            {
                y--;

                if(y >= 0)
                {
                    byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x) * bytesPerPixel;

                    color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);
                }
            }

            // Add the top most point on the antialiasing list
            if(y >= 0 && !compareColor(ocolor, color, 0))
            {
                [antiAliasingPoints pushFrontX:x andY:y];
            }

            y++;

            spanLeft = spanRight = NO;

            byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x) * bytesPerPixel;

            color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

            while (y < height && compareColor(ocolor, color, tolerance) && ncolor != color)
            {
                //Change old color with newColor RGBA value

                imageData[byteIndex + 0] = newRed;
                imageData[byteIndex + 1] = newGreen;
                imageData[byteIndex + 2] = newBlue;
                imageData[byteIndex + 3] = newAlpha;

                if(x > 0)
                {
                    byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x - 1) * bytesPerPixel;

                    color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

                    if(!spanLeft && x > 0 && compareColor(ocolor, color, tolerance))
                    {
                        [points pushFrontX:(x - 1) andY:y];

                        spanLeft = YES;
                    }
                    else if(spanLeft && x > 0 && !compareColor(ocolor, color, tolerance))
                    {
                        spanLeft = NO;
                    }

                    // we can't go left. Add the point on the antialiasing list
                    if(!spanLeft && x > 0 && !compareColor(ocolor, color, tolerance) && !compareColor(ncolor, color, tolerance))
                    {
                        [antiAliasingPoints pushFrontX:(x - 1) andY:y];
                    }
                }

                if(x < width - 1)
                {
                    byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x + 1) * bytesPerPixel;;

                    color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

                    if(!spanRight && compareColor(ocolor, color, tolerance))
                    {
                        [points pushFrontX:(x + 1) andY:y];

                        spanRight = YES;
                    }
                    else if(spanRight && !compareColor(ocolor, color, tolerance))
                    {
                        spanRight = NO;
                    }

                    // we can't go right. Add the point on the antialiasing list
                    if(!spanRight && !compareColor(ocolor, color, tolerance) && !compareColor(ncolor, color, tolerance))
                    {
                        [antiAliasingPoints pushFrontX:(x + 1) andY:y];
                    }
                }

                y++;

                if(y < height)
                {
                    byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x) * bytesPerPixel;

                    color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);
                }
            }

            if (y<height)
            {
                byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x) * bytesPerPixel;
                color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

                // Add the bottom point on the antialiasing list
                if (!compareColor(ocolor, color, 0))
                    [antiAliasingPoints pushFrontX:x andY:y];
            }
        }

        // For each point marked
        // perform antialiasing on the same pixel, plus the top,left,bottom and right pixel
        unsigned int antialiasColor = getColorCodeFromUIColor(newColor,bitmapInfo&kCGBitmapByteOrderMask );
        int red1   = ((0xff000000 & antialiasColor) >> 24);
        int green1 = ((0x00ff0000 & antialiasColor) >> 16);
        int blue1  = ((0x0000ff00 & antialiasColor) >> 8);
        int alpha1 =  (0x000000ff & antialiasColor);

        while ([antiAliasingPoints popFront:&x andY:&y] != INVALID_NODE_CONTENT)
        {
            byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x) * bytesPerPixel;
            color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

            if (!compareColor(ncolor, color, 0))
            {
                int red2   = ((0xff000000 & color) >> 24);
                int green2 = ((0x00ff0000 & color) >> 16);
                int blue2 = ((0x0000ff00 & color) >> 8);
                int alpha2 =  (0x000000ff & color);

                if (antiAlias) {
                    imageData[byteIndex + 0] = (red1 + red2) / 2;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 1] = (green1 + green2) / 2;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 2] = (blue1 + blue2) / 2;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 3] = (alpha1 + alpha2) / 2;
                } else {
                    imageData[byteIndex + 0] = red2;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 1] = green2;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 2] = blue2;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 3] = alpha2;
                }

#if DEBUG_ANTIALIASING
                imageData[byteIndex + 0] = 0;
                imageData[byteIndex + 1] = 0;
                imageData[byteIndex + 2] = 255;
                imageData[byteIndex + 3] = 255;
#endif
            }

            // left
            if (x>0)
            {
                byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x - 1) * bytesPerPixel;
                color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

                if (!compareColor(ncolor, color, 0))
                {
                    int red2   = ((0xff000000 & color) >> 24);
                    int green2 = ((0x00ff0000 & color) >> 16);
                    int blue2 = ((0x0000ff00 & color) >> 8);
                    int alpha2 =  (0x000000ff & color);

                    if (antiAlias) {
                        imageData[byteIndex + 0] = (red1 + red2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 1] = (green1 + green2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 2] = (blue1 + blue2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 3] = (alpha1 + alpha2) / 2;
                    } else {
                        imageData[byteIndex + 0] = red2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 1] = green2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 2] = blue2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 3] = alpha2;
                    }

#if DEBUG_ANTIALIASING
                    imageData[byteIndex + 0] = 0;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 1] = 0;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 2] = 255;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 3] = 255;
#endif
                }
            }
            if (x<width)
            {
                byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y)) + roundf(x + 1) * bytesPerPixel;
                color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

                if (!compareColor(ncolor, color, 0))
                {
                    int red2   = ((0xff000000 & color) >> 24);
                    int green2 = ((0x00ff0000 & color) >> 16);
                    int blue2 = ((0x0000ff00 & color) >> 8);
                    int alpha2 =  (0x000000ff & color);

                    if (antiAlias) {
                        imageData[byteIndex + 0] = (red1 + red2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 1] = (green1 + green2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 2] = (blue1 + blue2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 3] = (alpha1 + alpha2) / 2;
                    } else {
                        imageData[byteIndex + 0] = red2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 1] = green2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 2] = blue2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 3] = alpha2;
                    }

#if DEBUG_ANTIALIASING
                    imageData[byteIndex + 0] = 0;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 1] = 0;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 2] = 255;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 3] = 255;
#endif
                }

            }

            if (y>0)
            {
                byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y - 1)) + roundf(x) * bytesPerPixel;
                color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

                if (!compareColor(ncolor, color, 0))
                {
                    int red2   = ((0xff000000 & color) >> 24);
                    int green2 = ((0x00ff0000 & color) >> 16);
                    int blue2 = ((0x0000ff00 & color) >> 8);
                    int alpha2 =  (0x000000ff & color);

                    if (antiAlias) {
                        imageData[byteIndex + 0] = (red1 + red2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 1] = (green1 + green2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 2] = (blue1 + blue2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 3] = (alpha1 + alpha2) / 2;
                    } else {
                        imageData[byteIndex + 0] = red2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 1] = green2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 2] = blue2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 3] = alpha2;
                    }

#if DEBUG_ANTIALIASING
                    imageData[byteIndex + 0] = 0;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 1] = 0;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 2] = 255;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 3] = 255;
#endif
                }
            }

            if (y<height)
            {
                byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * roundf(y + 1)) + roundf(x) * bytesPerPixel;
                color = getColorCode(byteIndex, imageData);

                if (!compareColor(ncolor, color, 0))
                {
                    int red2   = ((0xff000000 & color) >> 24);
                    int green2 = ((0x00ff0000 & color) >> 16);
                    int blue2 = ((0x0000ff00 & color) >> 8);
                    int alpha2 =  (0x000000ff & color);

                    if (antiAlias) {
                        imageData[byteIndex + 0] = (red1 + red2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 1] = (green1 + green2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 2] = (blue1 + blue2) / 2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 3] = (alpha1 + alpha2) / 2;
                    } else {
                        imageData[byteIndex + 0] = red2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 1] = green2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 2] = blue2;
                        imageData[byteIndex + 3] = alpha2;
                    }

#if DEBUG_ANTIALIASING
                    imageData[byteIndex + 0] = 0;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 1] = 0;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 2] = 255;
                    imageData[byteIndex + 3] = 255;
#endif
                }

            }
        }

        //Convert Flood filled image row data back to UIImage object.

        CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage scale:[self scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

        CGImageRelease(newCGImage);

        CGContextRelease(context);

        free(imageData);

        return result;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Exception : %@", exception);
    }
}

/*
    I have used pure C function because it is said than C function is faster than Objective - C method in call.
    This two function are called most of time so it require that calling this work in speed.
    I have not verified this performance so I like to here comment on this.
*/
/*
    This function extract color from image and convert it to integer represent.
    Converting to integer make comperation easy.
*/
unsigned int getColorCode (unsigned int byteIndex, unsigned char *imageData)
{
    unsigned int red   = imageData[byteIndex];
    unsigned int green = imageData[byteIndex + 1];
    unsigned int blue  = imageData[byteIndex + 2];
    unsigned int alpha = imageData[byteIndex + 3];

    return (red << 24) | (green << 16) | (blue << 8) | alpha;
}

/*
    This function compare two color with counting tolerance value.

    If color is between tolerance rancge than it return true other wise false.
*/
bool compareColor (unsigned int color1, unsigned int color2, int tolorance)
{
    if(color1 == color2)
        return true;

    int red1   = ((0xff000000 & color1) >> 24);
    int green1 = ((0x00ff0000 & color1) >> 16);
    int blue1  = ((0x0000ff00 & color1) >> 8);
    int alpha1 =  (0x000000ff & color1);

    int red2   = ((0xff000000 & color2) >> 24);
    int green2 = ((0x00ff0000 & color2) >> 16);
    int blue2  = ((0x0000ff00 & color2) >> 8);
    int alpha2 =  (0x000000ff & color2);

    int diffRed   = abs(red2   - red1);
    int diffGreen = abs(green2 - green1);
    int diffBlue  = abs(blue2  - blue1);
    int diffAlpha = abs(alpha2 - alpha1);

    if( diffRed   > tolorance ||
        diffGreen > tolorance ||
        diffBlue  > tolorance ||
        diffAlpha > tolorance  )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

unsigned int getColorCodeFromUIColor(UIColor *color, CGBitmapInfo orderMask)
{
    //Convert newColor to RGBA value so we can save it to image.
    int newRed, newGreen, newBlue, newAlpha;

    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);

    if(CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor) == 2)
    {
        newRed   = newGreen = newBlue = components[0] * 255;
        newAlpha = components[1] * 255;
    }
    else if (CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor) == 4)
    {
        if (orderMask == kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little)
        {
            newRed   = components[2] * 255;
            newGreen = components[1] * 255;
            newBlue  = components[0] * 255;
            newAlpha = 255;
        }
        else
        {
            newRed   = components[0] * 255;
            newGreen = components[1] * 255;
            newBlue  = components[2] * 255;
            newAlpha = 255;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        newRed   = newGreen = newBlue = 0;
        newAlpha = 255;
    }

    unsigned int ncolor = (newRed << 24) | (newGreen << 16) | (newBlue << 8) | newAlpha;

    return ncolor;
}

@end
```

**LinkedListStack.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define FINAL_NODE_OFFSET -1
#define INVALID_NODE_CONTENT INT_MIN
typedef struct PointNode
{
    int nextNodeOffset;

    int point;

} PointNode;

@interface LinkedListStack : NSObject
{
    NSMutableData *nodeCache;

    int freeNodeOffset;
    int topNodeOffset;
    int _cacheSizeIncrements;

    int multiplier;
}

- (id)initWithCapacity:(int)capacity incrementSize:(int)increment andMultiplier:(int)mul;
- (id)initWithCapacity:(int)capacity;

- (void)pushFrontX:(int)x andY:(int)y;
- (int)popFront:(int *)x andY:(int *)y;
@end
```

**LinkedListStack.m**

```
#import "LinkedListStack.h"

@implementation LinkedListStack

#pragma mark - Initialisation
/*
    A linked List is create with size of <capicity>.
    When you add more element that <capicity> than Lisk List is incressed by size <increment>
    mul is value for H (for H see comment Stack methods)
*/
- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithCapacity:500];
}

- (id)initWithCapacity:(int)capacity
{
    return [self initWithCapacity:capacity incrementSize:500 andMultiplier:1000];
}

- (id)initWithCapacity:(int)capacity incrementSize:(int)increment andMultiplier:(int)mul
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        _cacheSizeIncrements = increment;

        int bytesRequired = capacity * sizeof(PointNode);

        nodeCache = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:bytesRequired];

        [self initialiseNodesAtOffset:0 count:capacity];

        freeNodeOffset = 0;
        topNodeOffset = FINAL_NODE_OFFSET;

        multiplier = mul;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Stack methods
/*
    X and Y are converted in single integer value (P) to push in stack.
    And again that value (P) are converted to X and Y when pop by using following equation:

    P = H * X + Y

    X = P / H;
    Y = P % H;

    H is same for all X and Y and must be grater than Y. So generaly Height is prefered value;
*/
- (void)pushFrontX:(int)x andY:(int)y;
{
    int p = multiplier * x + y;

    PointNode *node = [self getNextFreeNode];

    node->point = p;
    node->nextNodeOffset = topNodeOffset;

    topNodeOffset = [self offsetOfNode:node];
}

- (int)popFront:(int *)x andY:(int *)y;
{
    if(topNodeOffset == FINAL_NODE_OFFSET)
    {
        return INVALID_NODE_CONTENT;
    }

    PointNode *node = [self nodeAtOffset:topNodeOffset];

    int thisNodeOffset = topNodeOffset;

    // Remove this node from the queue
    topNodeOffset = node->nextNodeOffset;
    int value = node->point;

    // Reset it and add it to the free node cache
    node->point = 0;
    node->nextNodeOffset = freeNodeOffset;

    freeNodeOffset = thisNodeOffset;

    *x = value / multiplier;
    *y = value % multiplier;

    return value;
}

#pragma mark - utility functions
- (int)offsetOfNode:(PointNode *)node
{
    return node - (PointNode *)nodeCache.mutableBytes;
}

- (PointNode *)nodeAtOffset:(int)offset
{
    return (PointNode *)nodeCache.mutableBytes + offset;
}

- (PointNode *)getNextFreeNode
{
    if(freeNodeOffset < 0)
    {
        // Need to extend the size of the nodeCache
        int currentSize = nodeCache.length / sizeof(PointNode);
        [nodeCache increaseLengthBy:_cacheSizeIncrements * sizeof(PointNode)];

        // Set these new nodes to be the free ones
        [self initialiseNodesAtOffset:currentSize count:_cacheSizeIncrements];
        freeNodeOffset = currentSize;
    }

    PointNode *node = (PointNode*)nodeCache.mutableBytes + freeNodeOffset;
    freeNodeOffset = node->nextNodeOffset;

    return node;
}

- (void)initialiseNodesAtOffset:(int)offset count:(int)count
{
    PointNode *node = (PointNode *)nodeCache.mutableBytes + offset;

    for (int i=0; i<count - 1; i++)
    {
        node->point = 0;
        node->nextNodeOffset = offset + i + 1;
        node++;
    }

    node->point = 0;

    // Set the next node offset to make sure we don't continue
    node->nextNodeOffset = FINAL_NODE_OFFSET;
}
```

**CODE WHICH IS GIVING ERROR :-**

```
unsigned int getColorCode (unsigned int byteIndex, unsigned char *imageData)
{
    unsigned int red   = imageData[byteIndex];
    unsigned int green = imageData[byteIndex + 1];
    unsigned int blue  = imageData[byteIndex + 2];
    unsigned int alpha = imageData[byteIndex + 3];

    return (red << 24) | (green << 16) | (blue << 8) | alpha;
}
```

**SCREEN SHOTS**

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

**The Image Which is Giving me the error :-**

[image: Image 4]

Comment: Please share the image that crashes.

Comment: got the same error, any updates on this?

Comment: @JulioVasquez : i ended up using a different approach. give me your email. i'll send you the code.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this on an open issue of the github repo [here](https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill/issues/15)

The problem is on UIImage+Floodfill.m, at about line 60,

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
```

At about line 40 the class calls:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage];
```

so instead of obtaining the CGImageRef that way, I used the image's NSData:

```
CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)UIImagePNGRepresentation(self));

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

I made it a PNG because I was using the library to make an alpha flood-fill, instead of a solid color one. As long as the CGDataRef and CGImageRef are obtained from the same format, it fixed the bad access crash. Also, I did not include the release of memory that holds those objects as I do it later in the code, but just wanted to point it out.

A bit late answer but hopefully this would help anyone else using the code.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you call a deallocated object, its "zombie"
you can figure it out using following these steps:

1. Enable zombie objects in 'Edit Scheme'
2. Profile instead of normal run in Xcode (long press on run button)
3. Then use one of the instrument (ie. [zombie])

and record the activity

you can follow [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/EradicatingZombies.html)  as i dont have much reputation to post links more than two!